# How to scan large paper maps without a large format scanner?

Tags: raster

Is there a way people have used to import a paper map as a raster without using a large format scanner. I do not want to cut my map. I'm wondering how much success people have gotten using things like a regular digital camera, and what software they used to process the image to the point where I can just georeference it. I might even try something like microsofts photosynth software, or canons stitching software.

Comment: In most situations you will get better locational accuracy by georeferencing each image separately, rather than mosaicing the images and georeferencing the mosaic.

Answer (score 7):

I think if you want to use a camera, you would need to use a stand to ensure that the sensor is parallel to the map. I previously did this and mounted the camera using a monopod leg, clamped to the top of a bookcase. This enabled me to photograph 1m x 1m quite easily, and I didn't need to stitch anything together.

I think stitching it together using any program that deals with panoramas (photoshop or [gimp](http://www.shallowsky.com/software/pandora/), for example) should not be hard.

Comment: I've done a similar method and stitched together in Paint.NET: http://www.getpaint.net/download.html (free).

Comment: May have to try this. It's a rather large map (about 2 USGS quads in physical size). I tried a single picture of the whole map, and the resolution isn't nearly good enough.

Comment: @red If you used a point-and-shoot or even a high end camera (such as a DSLR) with a mediocre lens, you were getting about 0.5 mm resolution or worse with your image, which is marginal.  A DSLR (or larger format camera) with a large sensor and high-quality lens (corrected for geometric distortions in software with aperture optimally set around f/7 - f/8) will get about 0.2 mm resolution.  That's twice as good as the expected resolution from manual digitizing of the map (and exceeds national mapping standards in the US).  So a camera literally offers a decent one-shot solution when used right.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of megapixels you have - but an single image with a 5MP camera (say 2000x2500 pixels is only good for a small part of the map - maybe 8 inches x 10 inches @ 250dpi.

Answer (score 6):

To get an idea of what is possible, or just to be awed, have a look at the **About the Technology** section of the David Rumsey Historical Map Collection site, put up by 
Cartography Associates.

http://www.davidrumsey.com/about

Their optical capture and digitization methods are the gold standard in my opinion.

Comment: The collection is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you need another free (and working, as I experienced) sticher with fine defaults as well as an unbelievable number of manual settings try [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I gave this a try - I may need to read the documentation - it does what I want - but it seem best for images taken from a single point, just rotate the camera.

Comment: @redbeard: I've used this successfully for scanned maps. You can set the "camera" parameters to values that resemble a scanner. I was really happy with the results.

Comment: What kind of values did you use?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Autostitch](http://cvlab.epfl.ch/~brown/autostitch/autostitch.html) -- I have had great luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

You might try kinkos, Staples, or another engineering supply (our area has triangle A&E)
 They will have a large format scanner that you get get a raster on cd for $8-15.